# SSRS 2005 : Report border missing after exporting to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I want to have a border to my entire report. To achieve this I have added borders to Header, footer and body using following steps :

1. Right-click in the header outside any items in the header, and click
   Header Properties. On the Border tab, add a left, top, and right
   border with the style you want.
2. Right-click in the body outside any items on the design surface, and
   click Body Properties. On the Border tab, add a left and right
   border with the style you want.
3. Right-click in the footer outside any items in the footer, and click
   Footer Properties. On the Border tab, add a left, bottom, and right
   border with the style you want.

I have set the border width as 10pt. 
Report works great when viewed in browser, but when I export it to excel, it ends up with very thin boder.

Is there any workaround to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the excel border width cannot be of 10pt. The maximum is **Thick Box Border** in excel. Try to have a border width of 10pt in excel cell.

If above is true and you want achieve it any how, I have a bad trick for you. Put the report inside a table as shown and make the top, bottom, left and right cell of background black.

You can also handle it in main report (with out subreport) by using multiple Rectangles in header, footer and body.

[image]